# How to use CASE/WHEN in DB2 by using insert in a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, switch-statement

I have a stored procedure for DB2, where I want to fill a field named SEASON with W for Winter and S for Summer. The procedure is done, but I can't handle the logic. Can someone show me how this works?

This is for a dimension table in a data warehouse.

`INSERT into ABC.TIME_DIMEMSION (
    DATE,
    SEASON,
    QUERTER)
    VALUES(
    DATE(myDate),
    CASE
      WHEN MONTH(myDate) = 1 THEN
             SET SEASON= 'W';
      WHEN MONTH(myDate) = 2 THEN
             SET SEASON= 'W';
      WHEN MONTH(myDate) = 2 THEN
             SET SEASON= 'S';
      ELSE
             SET SEASON= 'X';
      END CASE.
      QUARTER(loaddate));`

I'm getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the description of the [CASE expression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023458.html) which you can use in other statements.

It differs from the [Case Statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005646.html).

You must use a `CASE expression` in your case:

```
INSERT into ABC.TIME_DIMEMSION (
    DATE,
    SEASON,
    QUERTER)
VALUES(
    DATE(myDate),
    CASE MONTH(myDate)
      WHEN 1 THEN 'X'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'Z'
    END,
    QUARTER(loaddate)
);

-- or

INSERT into ABC.TIME_DIMEMSION (
    DATE,
    SEASON,
    QUERTER)
VALUES(
    DATE(current timestamp),
    CASE 
      WHEN MONTH(current timestamp)=1 THEN 'X'
      WHEN MONTH(current timestamp)=2 THEN 'Y'
                                      ELSE 'Z'
    END,
    QUARTER(current timestamp)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (there are other ways) in a stored procedure:

*Note: do not use reserved words for table column-names!*

```
    declare v_season varchar(10);
    declare v_themonth integer;
    set v_themonth = month(somedate);

    set v_season = case when  v_themonth  in (12,1,2) then 'Winter'
        when v_themonth in (3,4,5) then 'Spring'
        when v_themonth in (6,7,8) then 'Summer'
        when v_themonth in (9,10,11) then 'Autumn'
        end;
    insert into abc.time_dimension( thedate, season) 
    values ( somedate, v_theseason);
```